# Eagle tstop layer problem

Tags: eaglecad

I'm about to update an old PCB design of mine using Eagle 7.5. The previous design used a DS18B20 and I want to replace that with a 1x3 0.1 pin header. 
[image: Eagle screenshot]

While I can delete the component from the schematic, some lines remain in the `tstop` layer (#29):

[image: Eagle screenshot]

How can I delete these lines? I can't move them and I don't want them in my new design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not objects on the `tStop` layer, they are outlines indicating where previous DRC errors were.

To get rid of them, simply run the DRC again.